# Entity Framework Tables Primary Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

This are my tables

Message
[image]

Person

[image]

This is my Gridview source

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Select" Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RecipientID" SortExpression="Person.LastName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Person.LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" 
            SortExpression="Subject" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Message1" HeaderText="Message" 
            SortExpression="Message1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
            SortExpression="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SenderID" SortExpression="Person.LastName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Person.LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the result
[image]

Can you guys help me to display the Sender's name ? :) Thank you guys in advance! I'm using Entity Datasource

**UPDATE**

I'm logging in as User Carlo

[image]

Sender display the user that's logged in not the true sender in the Message Table

this is my Entity Model

[image]

Comment: How do you display the recipient name? Sender name should be likewise.

Comment: wait i will upadte it to make more clearer

Comment: Person1 is the recipient. You better rename the navigation properties.

Comment: @GertArnold rename it to what sir?

Comment: What about "Sender" and "Recipient"? :) Wait, I'll put it in an answer.

Comment: the person 1 and person? then how will I bind it in Item Template? Sender.LastName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got the navigation properties you need for this, but their names conceal their role. You use `Message.Person` to get the sender's name, likewise you can user `Message.Person1` to get the recipient's name.

I would rename the properties `Person` and `Person1` into `Sender` and `Recipient`, respectively. Thus, they match the primitive foreign key names `SenderID` and `RecipientID`. Likewise, you could rename the `Person.Messages` properties into `MessagesSent` and `MessagesReceived`.

In the template you can use `Sender.LastName` and `Recipient.LastName`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Query

```
select m.MessageID,m.ReceipientID,m.Subject,m.senderID,p.UserName,p.FirseName from Message m inner join Person p on m.SenderID= p.ID
```

Comment: where should i put this query?

Comment: This is the select query for retrieve data from database. How you are querying? Is it by entity FW with LINQ ot Stored Procedure. If SP you can use the above query